# Start a javascript in a dropdown link?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get a link in my drop down menu to start my javascript(which has multiple functions) to play upon click in the same window. Now, it just plays when I load the screen(without clicking). Heres my code:

```
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="rockPaperScissors.js">
    </script>

</head>


<body>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Menu</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#" onclick="rockPaperScissors.js">rock, paper, scissors</a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the javascript code in rockPaperScissors.js in a function call. eg

```
function rockPaperScissors() { 
// all your code 
}
```

Then in your html

```
onclick="rockPaperScissors()"
```

Also please post rockPaperScissors.js if it already has a function wrapping it's code

Comment: @Bacon I love you too Bacon.. mmmm bacon.... Don't forget to mark as the accepted answer, or at least upvote my answer if it solved your issue

Comment: gladly, I spent way too much time trying to figure this out you just made my day